# How can I sort a vector of objects using string?

Tags: c++

I have a class like this:

```
class student
{
    public:
    string name;
    int age;
    int rollnum;
    int year;
    string father;
    string mother;
    string category;
    string region;
    char sex;
    string branch;
    int semester;
};
```

I have created a vector (vector j1) of such class student, and now I want to sort them on the basis of their name.

How can I do that?

PS: I did this.

```
student lessthan
{
    bool operator() (const student& h1, const student& h2)
    {
        return (h1.name < h2.name);
    }
};
```

And then did this,

```
sort(j1.begin(),j1.end(),lessthan());
```

But this shows an error saying expected primary expression before bool.

Comment: `lessthan` should be a `class`/`struct`. typo about `student` ?

Comment: `student` should be `struct`.

Comment: `char sex;` This is not exactly type-safe. It supposedly allows for `'M'` and `'F'`. Or `'m'` and `'f'`? Or both? What if someone accidentally assigns `'a'` or `'b'`, or 123 or 255 or 0? You should at least use an enum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sort( j1.begin(),
     j1.end(),
     [](const student& s1, const student& s2){ return s1.name < s2.name;} );
```

Comment: `begin(j1)` instead of `j1.begin()` to be slightly more idiomatic.

Comment: Might want to explain that's a lambda.